# Can I deploy .net core application into google cloud using terminal?

Tags: .net-core, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci

I would like to deploy my dotNetCore application into google cloud (App Engine Flex) using gitlab-ci or using Unix terminal. Unfortunately, I found limited information how can I do it. Could someone help me?

Yes, there is a possibility to [use docker](https://scotch.io/tutorials/google-cloud-platform-i-deploy-a-docker-app-to-google-container-engine-with-kubernetes), if I find no other options.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/? If you did, did you try it? If you tried it, what didn't work?

Comment: It requires to have VS tools installed. I need set of terminal commands that can be executed on Unix environment to deploy an application into App Engine Flex.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart for example says VS tools are only required if you are using VS. There are command line versions of all examples there too. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  This page describes how:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart

It's a little trickier than using VS Tools, but not much.  You have to create an app.yaml file, and populate it with two lines.  Then run:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet publish -c Release
gcloud app deploy .\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\publish\app.yaml
```

Again, the quickstart page and the samples it links to have the finer details.